# angular data binding linked to href

Tags: angular

I'm trying to get an h3 title according to what page of the website you're on. Here's my code

```
<h3 class="text-center m-5" *ngFor="let title of titles">{{feature.title}}</h3>
```

and typescript

```
titles: any[] = [
  { title: "ACTIVITY" },
  { title: "CHILL ZONE" },
  { title: "EVENTS" },
  { title: "ON THE ROAD" }
];
```

Thanks so much for the precious help on how to do this but most importantly on where to find the info on how to do this.

Comment: Please read about the [`NgForOf`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf) directive. You're iterating over `titles` array, and referring the current item as `title`. So, `feature` is `undefined` in your template, and that's why it won't work. Use `title.title` instead of `feature.title`, as mentioned in one of the answers.

Comment: thank you I'll look into that. A friend who's a coder helped to ask the question better. It gave a possible answer of ngIf. English not being my primary language at times it's hard to formulate the question correctly. So I'll look into ngForOf ans ngIf. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

just use

```
<h3 class="text-center m-5" *ngFor="let title of titles">{{title.title}}</h3>
```

without feature.

Comment: On my navbar, when you click on a link and that takes you to a page, I want the h3 to show the name of the page in question. Is that more clear?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to display each element of titles array in h3 ?? Try with {{title }}

Comment: On my navbar, when you click on a link and that takes you to a page, I want the h3 to show the name of the page in question. Is that more clear?